# TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'. In class inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, class-hierarchy

Let say I have a class hierarchy like so:

```
// monorepo/src/package1/file1.ts
export class AbstractModel implements Hashable {

    assignFromHash(hash: Object): void {
        Object.assign(this, hash);
    }
}

// monorepo/src/package2/file2.ts
export abstract class Model extends AbstractModel {}

// monorepo/src/package2/file3.ts
export class ModelImpl extends Model {}

// monorepo/src/application/file4.ts somewhere in application.
// Here object `model`, because of the angular DI setup,
// is an instance of ModelImpl
(model: Model ) => {
    model.assignFromHash({});
}
```

When compiling this with `tsc -p .` and the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
  "lib": [
    "dom",
    "es2015"
  ],
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es5"
},
"include": [
  "./**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules"
],
"compileOnSave": false,
"atom": {
  "rewriteTsconfig": false
}
```

}

I am getting:

```
error TS2339: Property 'assignFromHash' does not exist on type 'Model'.
```

What am I missing? How to fix this?

Note:

- The reason to have the intermediate class `Model` is to be able to use the DI functionality from Angular when [registering providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#registering-providers-in-an-ngmodule). I can not use an interface due to obvious limitation with typescript interfaces and javascript. I can not use `AbstractModel` neither because it would be too general then.
- The `monorepo` repository is handled with [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)
- There was no syntax error. The dots was just a way to state that it was an `object` placeholder, real code there is a correctly defined object hash.

This issue, as usual, was due to incorrect understanding of what was happening under the hood. I will post results as an answer in order to stick to stack overflow ways.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your presented code compiles without errors:

```
export interface Hashable { }
export class AbstractModel implements Hashable {
  assignFromHash(hash: Object): void {
    Object.assign(this, hash);
  }
}
export abstract class Model extends AbstractModel { }
export class ModelImpl extends Model { }
console.log((model: Model) => {
  model.assignFromHash({}); // No error
});
```

## Demo

[image]

## More

If you manage to reproduce the error again, please open a new question.

Comment: Hi @basarat , I just edit my question and posted what the real error was. Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i did not define properly (fully) the scenario. In this case my intermediate implementation model `Model` also implements some others interfaces, lets call it `ModelInterface` and the usage in code was exactly using this type, so instead:

```
(model: Model ) => {
    model.assignFromHash({});
}
```

I had this:

```
(model: ModelInterface ) => {
    model.assignFromHash({});
}
```

And of course `ModelInterface` has other definition, not containing `assignFromHash()` method. That's why typescript had no way to resolve the method from given type.

So thanks again for taking care and apologize for the time used.

Cheers